# Missing javax.transaction.jta artifact

Tags: maven, jta

I am getting this missing artifact message for

> javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B`as`403 Forbidden

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B from http://
 repository.jboss.com/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until 
 the update interval of jboss has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
 javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B from/to jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to 
 http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar. Error code 403, Forbidden
```

My `pom.xml` has:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

***Could you please tell me how to resolve this?***

Comment: try this repo `<url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, remove the `maven2` token from the end of the JBoss repository URL.

And add the Java.net Maven repository :

```
<repository>
    <id>java.net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: I don't why, but it really solved the issue. Thanks!