# eclipse maven error: Archive for required library in project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

In an eclipse maven project using spring web mvc, I am getting the following error in the Markers tab:

```
Archive for required library: 'D:/mypath/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar' in project 'DocumentManager' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

I have checked, and the jar file is in fact present in the url indicated.  I even copied a backup of the jar to overwrite the jar file in that location, but that did not get rid of the error either. I forced maven to update, which did not solve the problem.  I also restarted eclipse to no effect.

At one point, jta-1.0.1B.jar had been jta-1.0.1B.jar.LatestUpdate, so I shortened the name to jta-1.0.1B.jar

In pom.xml, the location of the error message is line 2, which reads as follows:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

When I download jta-1.0.1B.jar manually from [this url](http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/), the error in pom.xml goes away but is replaced with new errors in .java class files indicating that 5 methods of the Document class are not valid.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086523/missing-artifact-javax-transactionjtajar1-0-1b-issue-was-different-as-you-m) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003298/missing-javax-transaction-jta-artifact), but I am not using struts, I am already including 3.3.2.ga of hibernate, and I do not have a repository tag in pom.xml (which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086523/missing-artifact-javax-transactionjtajar1-0-1b-issue-was-different-as-you-m) said did not even solve the problem anyway), so I do not think this is a duplicate.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this problem?  If I need a repository tag, where do I put it?  And what else do I change to accommodate its addition?

For anyone who is curious, my pom.xml is included for reference as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- dependency to fix JSPServletException -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.32</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>               
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <groupId>DocumentManager</groupId>
  <artifactId>DocumentManager</artifactId>
</project>
```

Comment: The **.LatestUpdate** file isn't a jar file. It merely contains a timestamp (among some other things). So basically by renaming this file you created an invalid jar file. Remove the directory from your repository (and that should force Maven to pull in a fresh jar).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. I followed your instructions and Maven pulled another copy of .LastUpdated and did not include the jar.  Sounds like an error at the server level, but how do I work around it to get my jar so my application will run?

Answer (score 15):

To fix issues like that, let Maven download the files again:

1. Delete the folder `D:/mypath/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta`
2. Run Maven with `-U` so it tries broken downloads again.

That should try to download the file again and clean up any "residue" in your local repository.

If Eclipse still complains that the JAR file is corrupt:

1. Refresh your project (<kbd>F5</kbd> or from the context menu)
2. Clean the project
3. Try to open the JAR file. Maybe it's really corrupt.

If the JAR file is corrupt, delete the folder again and run Maven once more. Note the URLs which Maven used to download the archive and contact the administrator of that site.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually go to the repository specified in the error console
that is
 `Archive for required library: '**D:/mypath/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar**' in project 'DocumentManager' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file`

Delete the JAR mentioned

Go to eclipse, right click the project and select run as->maven-install.
It will download the right jar file.

Comment: Thank you and+1 for taking the time to add insight into this old question.

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude JTA in your hibernate dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction</artifactId>
            <groupId>jta</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After that, add the jta dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with me was fixed by going to `Build Path-> Configure Build Path-> Libraries-> Remove the jta lib` which has small cross mark on it.

I was able to successfully build my project but was getting this error even after project Refresh/Project Clean.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for adding perspective for future readers of this old posting.

Answer (score 0):

The maven central repository doesn't contain a jar file for the given groupId/artifactId only a **pom.xml**.

[image: maven central results]

You are using Spring 3.2 so I suggest you simply upgrade hibernate to the most recent version (4.2.6.Final) which should have a reference to jta 1.1. Or simply include the 1.1 version in your pom which does have a jar in maven central.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue simply.

1. select all libraries in "Maven Dependencies" of related project.
2. just do "Refresh" of mouse right button...

The reason is cache info, so just refresh the information.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with 1.5.5 Release jar and it worked for me

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
```

[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.5.RELEASE](http://Maven)