# Type Archive for required library: spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar' in project 'starter' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, m2e, spring-boot

While importing Spring Starter [zipped project generated by Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/) in Eclipse (STS　3.4) I got error

> Type Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar' in project 'starter' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Is it Eclipse problem or is there something special about `spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar` ?
Its size is 979016B.

Update: trying Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20093533/482717 to [eclipse maven error: Archive for required library in project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091177/eclipse-maven-error-archive-for-required-library-in-project-cannot-be-read-or-i)

When running `mvn package -U`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.0.1.RELEASE\spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar时出错; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.0.1.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar时出错; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.0.1.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar时出错; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.0.1.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar时出错; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.0\logback-core-1.1.0.jar时出错; invalid CEN header (bad signature)
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.0.1.RELEASE\spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar时出错; cannot read zip file entry
[ERROR] 读取C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.0.1.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar时出错; cannot read zip file entry
[ERROR] /D:/Workspaces/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/starter/src/main/java/demo/Application.java:[5,46] 程序包org.springframework.context.annotation不存在
[ERROR] /D:/Workspaces/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/starter/src/main/java/demo/Application.java:[7,2] 找不到符号
[ERROR] 符号: 类 ComponentScan
[ERROR] /D:/Workspaces/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/starter/src/main/java/demo/Application.java:[12,30] 无法访问org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
[ERROR] 找不到org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext的类文件
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

`invalid LOC header (bad signature)` but now for many spring jars.

```
D:\Workspaces\workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE\starter>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 16:44:56+0800)
Maven home: D:\Progs\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
D:\Workspaces\workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE\starter>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the corresponding .jar files from local repository and reissuing the maven command did the trick. It seems the .jar files got corrupted while downloading.