# Spring boot web starter application showing error

Tags: spring-boot

The spring boot web application (sts-bundle) is showing the error:
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar' in project 'demo' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Can anyone help me with this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [link](https://crunchify.com/cannot-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file-how-to-fix-maven-build-path-error-with-corrupted-jar-file/).
may be your jar files are corrupted.

Comment: I have deleted the file and updated the project, but I still have this issue

Comment: which file do you delete?  try to delete files from m2 repo ,update the maven project  and try to run the project

Comment: see stack over flow answer 
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670104/type-archive-for-required-library-spring-core-4-0-1-release-jar-in-project-st?rq=1] []