# Archive for rquired library cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I changed a simple maven project to a maven dynamic web project
adding this line to my pom.xml:

```
...
<packaging>war</packaging>
....
```

I updated my project using `maven -> update project` The m2e plugin now rewrote the project meta-files (.project and .classpath, as well as files in the .settings folder).

After it was done i got an error in my build path:

```
Archive for required library: 
'~/m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orient-commons/1.6.5/orient-
commons-1.6.5.pom' in project 'RelationExtraction' 
cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP
```

The maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Also i cant run my main anymore:

```
Error: main class myPackage.main.Main could not be found or loaded
```

I tried the following:

1. I deleted all folders in my `~/m2/` folder and updated my project again
2. I restarted eclipse
3. I closed and reopened my project
4. I restarted my computer

Inside the folder `~/m2/repository/com/orientechnologies/orient-commons/1.6.5/` are 
the following files:

- _maven.repositories
- orient-commons-1.6.5.jar
- orient-commons-1.6.5.jar.sha1
- orient-commons-1.6.5.pom
- orient-commons-1.6.5.pom.sha1

I can see in my Maven Dependencies in my project that maven is trying to load the pom and not the jar:

[image]

When i delete

```
...
<packaging>war</packaging>
....
```

Maven loads the correct jar and not the pom.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse maven error: Archive for required library in project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091177/eclipse-maven-error-archive-for-required-library-in-project-cannot-be-read-or-i)

Comment: No because the provided solutions didnt help me.

Comment: Try again to update your project (Maven -> Update project), but this time checking the box "force updates of snapshots/releases". This is the same as using the -U flag on the command line. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Yes i know that and i always do it like that. it does not work. i just dont get why maven wants to load the pom file of orient-commons-1.6.5 and not the jar file.

Comment: Show the dependency for that artifact.

Comment: updated: i added the maven dependency and a picture which shows the including of orient-commons-1.6.5.pom to my post.

Comment: How about trying to delete the project inside eclipse. Remove all eclipse files (.settings/.project/.classpath) and retry an import->existing maven project..? It is a rough eclipse reset, but it sometimes work