# Maven Error - Failure to find artifact in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository

Tags: java, maven

I don't understand following error I am getting while executing : `mvn install`

I have the `javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B` artifact in my m2 repository and I did make sure that the maven is looking at the right repository (By running `mvn -X`)
Has anybody ever experienced and resolved this kind of error.

**Failure to find javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced**

Comment: That error is telling you that you have a local entry in your repository that is not found in the maven repository.  I think you could live with the error - but shouldn't you update your dependency to the version that _is_ on the Maven repo?

Comment: Is there a way to disable/pass this error. Because of this error the build stops.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  The jar was installed in my local .m2 directory.

- I had the pom.xml updated with the dependency element for the jar file.
- I even added the localRepository element in a local settings.xml (even though this is the default and shouldn't be needed).
- The authorities on the directories was what is required:
  drwxr-xr-x on directories and -rw-r--r-- on the files in the respository
- none of the other items in the list from the DependencyResolutionException were helpful

I decided to try **running with sudo on the mvn install** and this made the difference (I am on a mac if that matters):
`sudo mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.nav.abc -  DartifactId=xy.abc -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -  Dfile=abcAdapter/xy.abc.jar`

And now it seems to be working!
I don't see any difference in the access authorities on the directories so I'm not sure how this made any difference... but it does work

Comment: It seems that the folder structure that maven creates takes some configuration that may be specific to your environment at that time. When I run your command, some files in that filegroup had changes in content. For exemple, the old -remote.repositories had an attribute like this "locator-1.0.0.pom>=". In the new -remote.repositories, this attribute is like this: "locator-1.0.0.pom>nexus=".

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the jar is in your local .m2, it is strange that Maven still goes to the central repo to find it, ideally it should not. I am thinking it might be related to a different dependency, for example like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285831/maven-missing-dependency-jta-1-0-1b). Could you check if yours if the same scenario?

The other thing you could do is look for a repository where this version of JTA exists and add that repository to your settings.xml or pom.xml, however you have that configured. 
One another option is you could try with a different version of JTA jar and see if you run in to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder contains `javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B` in your .m2 and then delete this file _remote.repositories